# Sveltekit how to call an api with a token

Tags: api, authentication, sveltekit

I currently have an API running on Nodejs Express where you can get or upload all types of files (images, videos...) as well as simple json responses.

I would like to connect Sveltekit to this API but it is secured with a SSO so I need to provide an access token for each request.

I already get the access token from the SSO (oidc) on sveltekit.

**Solution 1:**
a service workers intercept requests to the API and add the access token.

Problems: I don't want to build every time  but as the documentation says: service workers only work in the production build, not in development

**Solution 2:**
send requests to the svletekit backend and then pipe them to the API with the access token

Problems: Works only for basic requests but not for stream, it seems that it is supported recently (https://github.com/sveltejs/kit/issues/5344) but there is no documentation or example and this solution requires more resources (requests should be from the browser to the api)

**Solution 3:**
Hooks externalFetch
This function allows you to modify (or replace) a fetch request for an external resource that happens inside a load function that runs on the server (or during pre-rendering).

Problems: It doesn't work for requests like the src of an image

Any idea ?

**edit:** Solution, with the new version of sveltekit node-fetch has been replaced by Undici and the streams are functional, so it is possible to pipe requests from the backend.
For the dev it work well but it's not the best solution for production so you can use both depending on the environnement.